# WCF how to connect to multiple running callbacks

Tags: c#, wcf, concurrency, reentrancy

I've created a WCF solution where I can kick off several simultaneous long running processes that report progress and have the option to cancel each one individually.  I can disconnect the client and the processes keep running and I can start a new client and add an additional process and they all keep running simultaneously.  That part works great.

My question is how can I connect a second client to all of the already running callbacks and also have any processes added from the second client show up in the first client (if it's still running)?

Comment: `ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant` has 0 to do with your quesotion, edit it to a better title that reflects what your question is.

Comment: As to how to solve it, go look up how to implement a "Message Bus".

Comment: After googling Message Bus and not finding quite what I was looking for, I eventually stumbled upon a WCF Pub/Sub pattern that is exactly what I needed so thank you for pointing me in the general direction of the path I was looking for even though I didn't know how to describe it.  I'm sure you could have given better directions if I could have described what I wanted better. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF publisher/subscriber pattern is exactly what I needed I just didn't know how to ask it.